# The use of "out of"

Tags: phrases

The Sentence:
In 334 B.C., Alexander the Great took his Greek armies to the east and in only a few years completed his creation of an empire out of much of southwest Asia.

Question:
In this sentence, why does the author use "out of much of southwest Asia". What does he mean?

Comment: He means just what he says: Alexander did not conquer all of southwest Asia, just a big part of it.

Comment: Well, to say he created an empire is pushing it, surely. He never ruled it; he died before there was anything but a formal proclamation of empire, and it fell apart immediately into squabbling principalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/out):

> **out of**
>   1 Indicating the source or derivation of something; from.
>   *‘a bench fashioned out of a fallen tree trunk’*

In this case, the author means that Alexander created an empire whose territory was made from a large part of southwest Asia.